# IPicture properties showing error Excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, class, dictionary, winapi

I am on Windows 10 Enterprise 64 bit with Excel 2016 Pro 64 bit.

I am trying to add pictures to a Public Dictionary by first inserting them to a Worksheet of a temporary workbook and then copying the Shape to Windows Clipboard and then deleting the Shape from the worksheet.

The code works most of the time, but errors out sometimes (don't know the reason)! Also, the pictures show up as Nothing in Dictionary when i Add a Watch. The IPicture properties show `Application defined or object defined error.`

**Questions:**

- How do i resolve this issue?
- How do i load the pictures back from Dictionary into (Current workbook) a sheet?

[image]

The full code is:

**Class: clsPictures**

```
Option Explicit

'Public PicCollect As Object
Public Key As String
Public Value As Variant

'Private Sub Class_Initialize()
'    Set PicCollect = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
'End Sub
```

**Module1:**

```
    Option Explicit

    Public PicCollect As Object 'Collection
    Public KeyValuePair As clsPictures   'Collection

    '***************************************************************************'*
    '* AUTHOR & DATE:   STEPHEN BULLEN, Office Automation Ltd
    '*                  15 November 1998


    '*
    '* DESCRIPTION:     Creates a standard Picture object from whatever is on the clipboard.
    '*                  This object can then be assigned to (for example) and Image control
    '*                  on a userform.  The PastePicture function takes an optional argument of
    '*                  the picture type - xlBitmap or xlPicture.
    '*
    '*                  The code requires a reference to the "OLE Automation" type library
    '*
    '*                  The code in this module has been derived from a number of sources
    '*                  discovered on MSDN.
    '*
    '*                  To use it:
    '*                      Set Image1.Picture = PastePicture(xlPicture)
    '*                  to paste a picture of whatever is on the clipboard into a standard image control.
    '*
    '* PROCEDURES:
    '*   PastePicture   The entry point for the routine
    '*   CreatePicture  Private function to convert a bitmap or metafile handle to an OLE reference
    '*   fnOLEError     Get the error text for an OLE error code
    '***************************************************************************
    'Option Private Module
    Option Compare Text


    ''' User-Defined Types for API Calls


    'Declare a UDT to store a GUID for the IPicture OLE Interface
    Private Type guid
        Data1 As Long
        Data2 As Integer
        Data3 As Integer
        Data4(0 To 7) As Byte
    End Type


'''Windows API Function Declarations
#If VBA7 Then


    Private Type uPicDesc
        Size As Long
        Type As Long
        hPic As LongPtr
        hPal As LongPtr
    End Type


    'Does the clipboard contain a bitmap/metafile?
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function IsClipboardFormatAvailable Lib "user32" (ByVal wFormat As Integer) As Long


    'Open the clipboard to read
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function OpenClipboard Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr) As Long


    'Get a pointer to the bitmap/metafile
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetClipboardData Lib "user32" (ByVal wFormat As Integer) As LongPtr


    'Close the clipboard
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function CloseClipboard Lib "user32" () As Long


    'Convert the handle into an OLE IPicture interface.
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function OleCreatePictureIndirect Lib "oleaut32.dll" (PicDesc As uPicDesc, RefIID As guid, ByVal fPictureOwnsHandle As LongPtr, IPic As IPicture) As Long


    'Create our own copy of the metafile, so it doesn't get wiped out by subsequent clipboard updates.
    Declare PtrSafe Function CopyEnhMetaFile Lib "gdi32" Alias "CopyEnhMetaFileA" (ByVal hemfSrc As LongPtr, ByVal lpszFile As String) As LongPtr


    'Create our own copy of the bitmap, so it doesn't get wiped out by subsequent clipboard updates.
    Declare PtrSafe Function CopyImage Lib "user32" (ByVal Handle As LongPtr, ByVal un1 As Long, ByVal n1 As Long, ByVal n2 As Long, ByVal un2 As Long) As LongPtr


#Else


    'Declare a UDT to store the bitmap information
    Private Type uPicDesc
        Size As Long
        Type As Long
        hPic As Long
        hPal As Long
    End Type


    'Does the clipboard contain a bitmap/metafile?
    Private Declare Function IsClipboardFormatAvailable Lib "user32" (ByVal wFormat As Integer) As Long

    'Open the clipboard to read
    Private Declare Function OpenClipboard Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As Long) As Long

    'Get a pointer to the bitmap/metafile
    Private Declare Function GetClipboardData Lib "user32" (ByVal wFormat As Integer) As Long

    'Close the clipboard
    Private Declare Function CloseClipboard Lib "user32" () As Long

    'Convert the handle into an OLE IPicture interface.
    Private Declare Function OleCreatePictureIndirect Lib "olepro32.dll" (PicDesc As uPicDesc, RefIID As GUID, ByVal fPictureOwnsHandle As Long, IPic As IPicture) As Long

    'Create our own copy of the metafile, so it doesn't get wiped out by subsequent clipboard updates.
    Declare Function CopyEnhMetaFile Lib "gdi32" Alias "CopyEnhMetaFileA" (ByVal hemfSrc As Long, ByVal lpszFile As String) As Long

    'Create our own copy of the bitmap, so it doesn't get wiped out by subsequent clipboard updates.
    Declare Function CopyImage Lib "user32" (ByVal Handle As Long, ByVal un1 As Long, ByVal n1 As Long, ByVal n2 As Long, ByVal un2 As Long) As Long

#End If

'The API format types we're interested in
Const CF_BITMAP = 2
Const CF_PALETTE = 9
Const CF_ENHMETAFILE = 14
Const IMAGE_BITMAP = 0
Const LR_COPYRETURNORG = &H4
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
''' Subroutine: PastePicture
'''
''' Purpose:    Get a Picture object showing whatever's on the clipboard.
'''
''' Arguments:  lXlPicType - The type of picture to create.  Can be one of:
'''                          xlPicture to create a metafile (default)
'''                          xlBitmap to create a bitmap
'''
''' Date        Developer           Action
''' ------------------------------------------------------c--------------------
''' 30 Oct 98   Stephen Bullen      Created
''' 15 Nov 98   Stephen Bullen      Updated to create our own copies of the clipboard images



'To operate......adjust sheetname, foldername/path and file extension to suit
Sub DoIT()

    Dim strFolder$
    strFolder = "C:\Images\"
    If Not PicCollection("PicSht", strFolder, "png") Then MsgBox "Picture collection NOT created!"

End Sub

Sub TestPics()
    Dim wk As Worksheet, Key, i&
    Set wk = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PicSht")

    i = 0
    With wk
        For Each Key In PicCollect.Keys
            MsgBox Key
            .Shapes.AddPicture PicCollect(Key), msoFalse, msoCTrue, 50 + i, 50, PicCollect(Key).Width, PicCollect(Key).Height
            i = i + 50
        Next Key
    End With

End Sub

Public Function PicCollection(ShtName As String, Flder As String, Filext As String) As Boolean

    Dim FSO As Object, FolDir As Object, FileNm As Object, Shp As Shape, Ws As Worksheet

    'Call PicCollection("sheet1", "C:\Pftrial", "gif")

    'Loads pics into collection
    On Error GoTo ErFix
'    Set PicCollect = New Collection
    Set PicCollect = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
    Set FolDir = FSO.GetFolder(Flder)
    Set Ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ShtName)
    With Ws
        For Each Shp In .Shapes
            If Shp.Type = msoPicture Then
                Shp.Delete
            End If
        Next Shp
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    'loop files
    For Each FileNm In FolDir.Files
        If FileNm.Name Like "*." & Filext Then
            Set Shp = Ws.Shapes.AddPicture(Flder & "\" & FileNm.Name, False, True, 100, 100, 1, 1)

            'Use picture'Shp height and width.
            Shp.ScaleHeight 1, msoCTrue
            Shp.ScaleWidth 1, msoCTrue
            Shp.CopyPicture appearance:=xlPrinter, Format:=xlPicture

            If Not PicCollect.Exists(FileNm.Name) Then
'                PicCollect.Add Key:=FileNm.Name, Item:=PastePicture
                Set KeyValuePair = New clsPictures
                KeyValuePair.Key = FileNm.Name: Set KeyValuePair.Value = PastePicture
'                PicCollect.Add Key:=KeyValuePair.Key, Item:=KeyValuePair.Value
                Set PicCollect(KeyValuePair.Key) = KeyValuePair.Value
                Shp.Delete
            End If
        End If
    Next FileNm

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Set FSO = Nothing
    Set FolDir = Nothing
    PicCollection = True
    Exit Function

ErFix:
    MsgBox Err.Number & "_" & Err.Description
    On Error GoTo 0
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Set FSO = Nothing
    Set FolDir = Nothing
    PicCollection = False

End Function

Function PastePicture(Optional lXlPicType As Long = xlPicture) As IPicture

#If VBA7 Or Win64 Then
PastePictureVBA7 (lXlPicType)
#Else
PastePictureWin32 (lXlPicType)
#End If

End Function

Function PastePictureVBA7(Optional lXlPicType As Long = xlPicture) As IPicture


    'Some pointers
    Dim H As Long, hPicAvail As Long, hPtr As LongPtr, hPal As LongPtr, lPicType As Long, hCopy As LongPtr

    'Convert the type of picture requested from the xl constant to the API constant
    lPicType = IIf(lXlPicType = xlBitmap, CF_BITMAP, CF_ENHMETAFILE)

    'Check if the clipboard contains the required format
    hPicAvail = IsClipboardFormatAvailable(lPicType)

    If hPicAvail <> 0 Then
        'Get access to the clipboard
        H = OpenClipboard(0&)

        If H > 0 Then
            'Get a handle to the image data
            hPtr = GetClipboardData(lPicType)

            'Create our own copy of the image on the clipboard, in the appropriate format.
            If lPicType = CF_BITMAP Then
                hCopy = CopyImage(hPtr, IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_COPYRETURNORG)
            Else
                hCopy = CopyEnhMetaFile(hPtr, vbNullString)
            End If

            'Release the clipboard to other programs
            Do
                H = CloseClipboard
                DoEvents
                EmptyClipboard
                DoEvents
            Loop Until H = 0

            'If we got a handle to the image, convert it into a Picture object and return it
            If hPtr <> 0^ Then Set PastePictureVBA7 = CreatePictureVBA7(hCopy, 0, lPicType)
        End If
    End If
End Function


Function PastePictureWin32(Optional lXlPicType As Long = xlPicture) As IPicture


    'Some pointers
    Dim H As Long, hPicAvail As Long, hPtr As Long, hPal As Long, lPicType As Long, hCopy As Long

    'Convert the type of picture requested from the xl constant to the API constant
    lPicType = IIf(lXlPicType = xlBitmap, CF_BITMAP, CF_ENHMETAFILE)

    'Check if the clipboard contains the required format
    hPicAvail = IsClipboardFormatAvailable(lPicType)

    If hPicAvail <> 0 Then
        'Get access to the clipboard
        H = OpenClipboard(0&)

        If H > 0 Then
            'Get a handle to the image data
            hPtr = GetClipboardData(lPicType)

            'Create our own copy of the image on the clipboard, in the appropriate format.
            If lPicType = CF_BITMAP Then
                hCopy = CopyImage(hPtr, IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_COPYRETURNORG)
            Else
                hCopy = CopyEnhMetaFile(hPtr, vbNullString)
            End If

            'Release the clipboard to other programs
            Do
                H = CloseClipboard
                DoEvents
                EmptyClipboard
                DoEvents
            Loop Until H = 0

            'If we got a handle to the image, convert it into a Picture object and return it
            If hPtr <> 0 Then Set PastePictureWin32 = CreatePicture(hCopy, 0, lPicType)
        End If
    End If

End Function
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
''' Subroutine: CreatePicture
'''
''' Purpose:    Converts a image (and palette) handle into a Picture object.
'''
'''             Requires a reference to the "OLE Automation" type library
'''
''' Arguments:  None
'''
''' Date        Developer           Action
''' --------------------------------------------------------------------------
''' 30 Oct 98  Stephen Bullen      Created
'''
Private Function CreatePictureVBA7(ByVal hPic As LongPtr, ByVal hPal As LongPtr, ByVal lPicType) As IPicture


    ' IPicture requires a reference to "OLE Automation"
    Dim r As Long, uPicInfo As uPicDesc, IID_IDispatch As guid, IPic As IPicture


    'OLE Picture types
    Const PICTYPE_BITMAP = 1
    Const PICTYPE_ENHMETAFILE = 4


    ' Create the Interface GUID (for the IPicture interface)
    With IID_IDispatch
        .Data1 = &H7BF80980
        .Data2 = &HBF32
        .Data3 = &H101A
        .Data4(0) = &H8B
        .Data4(1) = &HBB
        .Data4(2) = &H0
        .Data4(3) = &HAA
        .Data4(4) = &H0
        .Data4(5) = &H30
        .Data4(6) = &HC
        .Data4(7) = &HAB
    End With


    ' Fill uPicInfo with necessary parts.
    With uPicInfo
        .Size = Len(uPicInfo)                                                   ' Length of structure.
        .Type = IIf(lPicType = CF_BITMAP, PICTYPE_BITMAP, PICTYPE_ENHMETAFILE)  ' Type of Picture
        .hPic = hPic                                                            ' Handle to image.
        .hPal = IIf(lPicType = CF_BITMAP, hPal, 0)                              ' Handle to palette (if bitmap).
    End With

        ' Create the Picture object.
    r = OleCreatePictureIndirect(uPicInfo, IID_IDispatch, 1, IPic)


    ' If an error occured, show the description
    If r <> 0 Then Debug.Print "Create Picture: " & fnOLEError(r)


    ' Return the new Picture object.
    Set CreatePictureVBA7 = IPic


End Function


Private Function CreatePicture(ByVal hPic As Long, ByVal hPal As Long, ByVal lPicType) As IPicture


    ' IPicture requires a reference to "OLE Automation"
    Dim r As Long, uPicInfo As uPicDesc, IID_IDispatch As guid, IPic As IPicture


    'OLE Picture types
    Const PICTYPE_BITMAP = 1
    Const PICTYPE_ENHMETAFILE = 4


    ' Create the Interface GUID (for the IPicture interface)
    With IID_IDispatch
        .Data1 = &H7BF80980
        .Data2 = &HBF32
        .Data3 = &H101A
        .Data4(0) = &H8B
        .Data4(1) = &HBB
        .Data4(2) = &H0
        .Data4(3) = &HAA
        .Data4(4) = &H0
        .Data4(5) = &H30
        .Data4(6) = &HC
        .Data4(7) = &HAB
    End With


    ' Fill uPicInfo with necessary parts.
    With uPicInfo
        .Size = Len(uPicInfo)                                                   ' Length of structure.
        .Type = IIf(lPicType = CF_BITMAP, PICTYPE_BITMAP, PICTYPE_ENHMETAFILE)  ' Type of Picture
        .hPic = hPic                                                            ' Handle to image.
        .hPal = IIf(lPicType = CF_BITMAP, hPal, 0)                              ' Handle to palette (if bitmap).
    End With


    ' Create the Picture object.
    r = OleCreatePictureIndirect(uPicInfo, IID_IDispatch, True, IPic)


    ' If an error occured, show the description
    If r <> 0 Then Debug.Print "Create Picture: " & fnOLEError(r)


    ' Return the new Picture object.
    Set CreatePicture = IPic


End Function


''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
''' Subroutine: fnOLEError
'''
''' Purpose:    Gets the message text for standard OLE errors
'''
''' Arguments:  None
'''
''' Date        Developer           Action
''' --------------------------------------------------------------------------
''' 30 Oct 98   Stephen Bullen      Created
'''


Private Function fnOLEError(lErrNum As Long) As String


    'OLECreatePictureIndirect return values
    Const E_ABORT = &H80004004
    Const E_ACCESSDENIED = &H80070005
    Const E_FAIL = &H80004005
    Const E_HANDLE = &H80070006
    Const E_INVALIDARG = &H80070057
    Const E_NOINTERFACE = &H80004002
    Const E_NOTIMPL = &H80004001
    Const E_OUTOFMEMORY = &H8007000E
    Const E_POINTER = &H80004003
    Const E_UNEXPECTED = &H8000FFFF
    Const S_OK = &H0


    Select Case lErrNum
    Case E_ABORT
        fnOLEError = " Aborted"
    Case E_ACCESSDENIED
        fnOLEError = " Access Denied"
    Case E_FAIL
        fnOLEError = " General Failure"
    Case E_HANDLE
        fnOLEError = " Bad/Missing Handle"
    Case E_INVALIDARG
        fnOLEError = " Invalid Argument"
    Case E_NOINTERFACE
        fnOLEError = " No Interface"
    Case E_NOTIMPL
        fnOLEError = " Not Implemented"
    Case E_OUTOFMEMORY
        fnOLEError = " Out of Memory"
    Case E_POINTER
        fnOLEError = " Invalid Pointer"
    Case E_UNEXPECTED
        fnOLEError = " Unknown Error"
    Case S_OK
        fnOLEError = " Success!"
    End Select
End Function
```

Comment: " errors out sometimes" - exactly how does that look when it happens?

Comment: @TimWilliams it happens on line CloseClipboard. same `Application defined or Object defined error`. So i had put that Do..DoEvents...Loop Until H=0...But still it happens. So not sure if that is the case. Also, even when it works, the IPicture object doesn't display any properties but shows errors. See the above image.